# Use the s (star) argument with \NewDocumentEnvironment

Tags: environments, xparse

Would it be possible to use the `s` argument specifier of `xparse` in `\NewDocumentEnvironment` so that we get an environment an a starred version of it?

Actually it works, but the star goes to the wrong place:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{baz}{s O{Foobar}}{%
   \begin{quote}
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \textbf{#2 (starred)}\quad
   }{%
      \textbf{#2 (non-starred)}
   }%
}{%
   \end{quote}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{baz}
   \lipsum[2]
\end{baz}
\lipsum[3]
% Star at the wrong place in a LaTeX2e sense
\begin{baz}*[Name]
   \lipsum[2]
\end{baz}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

It would be great if `\NewDocumentEnvironment{baz}{s ...` defines `{baz}` and `{baz*}`, otherwise one have to define them separately as in 2e syntax…

Comment: I have some thoughts on how to tackle this, but they are really 'for discussion' (i.e. they don't make a good Q&A answer). For example, you could imagine definition `\begin` to check for an optional star (there is a bit of complexity to it). However, with LaTeX2e that means messing with some internals: not sure if it's a great idea. One for LaTeX-L!

Comment: It is 2017 and the `xparse` neither mentions this problem nor does it suggest a possible fix. I see that reading the docs strictly implies the current behavior, but it doesn't seem desirable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just say

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{baz}{s O{Foobar}}{%
   \begin{quote}
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
      \textbf{#2 (starred)}\quad
   }{%
      \textbf{#2 (non-starred)}
   }%
}{%
   \end{quote}
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:cpn {baz*} {\baz*}
\cs_new_eq:cN {endbaz*} \endbaz
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and now `\begin{baz*}...\end{baz*}` will do as expected.

I'm not certain that an extension of the syntax in this sense is good: the environment's name is the argument to `\begin`.