# How to define a starred version of an environment in LaTeX

Tags: environments, starred-version

I am interested in defining a new environment in LaTeX that has a starred version. How is this done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since the `\newenvironment` command uses a `\csname`, you can define it directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{test*}
{start}{end}
\begin{document}
\begin{test*}
hello
\end{test*}
\end{document}
```

You can have any combination of characters (with catcode 11 and 12) as you would in a `\csname...\endcsname` construct,

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{test123*}
{start}{end}
\begin{document}
\begin{test123*}
hello
\end{test123*}
\end{document}
```

What you do with the starred command is up to you.

Comment: I thought it would be much more complicated than this :-) I should have tried it myself before I asked.

Comment: @digital-Ink It's a sort of a hidden feature.

Comment: If you were to define a command, `xparse` would allow to handle the starred and non-starred case in one definition. For environments, [the solution however is less beautiful](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45401).

Comment: @dgs One issue for `xparse` is that it's defining environments that work with LaTeX2e and so follow the LaTeX2e rules. I have in mind an approach to deal with this, but it has to work when you _use_ an environment and not when you _define_ it. That could break LaTeX2e code, so can't really go into `xparse`. I might look to put a demo together over the next few days.

Comment: @Yiannis saying "any combination of characters" is perhaps a little misleading as one is only allowed to use characters with catcode 11 and 12, e.g. \newenvironment{foo$} isn't working.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Thanks! I thought I covered that when I said ... as you would normally use in a `\csname...\endcsname` construct, but I will add a clarification.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach `\newenvironment{abc$}{\quote}{\endquote}` works for me. However you can't define an `abc#` environment, nor `abc^^`, but for different reasons.

Comment: Right, I have a solution for the starred environment business: if it works, it will be in the next `xparse` update

Comment: @egreg you are right $ is ok, \csname considers more things characters then TeX does in other places (and something I didn't remember correctly).

Comment: @egreg But you can define `$abc^2$` if you wish:)

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Also `\newenvironment{{f}{o}{o}}` works, but I've some doubts whether this can be useful. `;-)`