# Modify label reference printing on-the-fly

Tags: cross-referencing, latex3

This question is a little harder to explain without a brief description of the Maximal Working Example which includes the main functionality of [a package I'm writing](https://github.com/zoqaeski/teachingtools), so I've included this below before actually getting to the point:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \__teachingtools_print_question: {
    \str_clear_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_str
    \str_put_left:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_str { Question }
    \bool_if:NT \l__teachingtools_numbered_question_bool {
        \refstepcounter{question}
        \str_put_right:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_str { ~ }
        \__teachingtools_print_question_label:
        \str_put_right:Nx \l__teachingtools_question_str { \l__teachingtools_question_label_str }
    }
    \str_put_right:Nx \l__teachingtools_question_str { \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str }

    % Prints format string of label in terminal: how can I use this to change the
    % printing of \refl{qu:label}?
    % \tl_show:N \l__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl
    % It can be used as an argument to `\renewcommand\thequestion`, and appears to work, with the caveat that the redefinition is local to the group created by each environment instance.
    \renewcommand\thequestion{ \l__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl }

    \par \skip_vertical:N \l__teachingtools_questionbefore_skip
    \group_begin:
    \bfseries \l__teachingtools_question_str \par\nopagebreak
    \group_end:
}
\cs_new:Nn \__teachingtools_print_question_label: {
    \str_clear_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_label_str
    \tl_clear_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl
    \bool_if:NT \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool {
        \str_put_right:Nx \l__teachingtools_question_label_str { \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl }
        \str_put_right:Nx \l__teachingtools_question_label_str { \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str }
        \tl_put_right:NV \l__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl { \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl }
        \tl_put_right:NV \l__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl { \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str }
    }
    \str_put_right:Nx \l__teachingtools_question_label_str { \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl }
    \tl_put_right:NV \l__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl { \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl }
}
\newcounter{question}
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools / question } {
    reset .default:n = section,
    reset .choices:nn = {
        part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
    }
    {
        \counterwithin*{question}{ \tl_to_str:N \l_keys_choice_tl }
    },
    reset / none .code:n = {
        \counterwithout*{question}{section}
    },
}
\bool_new:N \l__teachingtools_numbered_question_bool
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    question / number .code:n = {
        \int_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_int #1
        \int_decr:N \l_tmpa_int
        \setcounter{question}{ \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
    },
}
\str_new:N \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    prefix-separator .choice:,
    prefix-separator / dash .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str { - }
    },
    prefix-separator / dot .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str { . }
    },
    prefix-separator / colon .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nx \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str { \c_colon_str }
    },
    prefix-separator / none .code:n = {
        \str_gclear:N \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str
    },
    prefix-separator .default:n = none,
    prefix-separator .initial:n = none,
}
\tl_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl
\bool_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools / question } {
    prefix .choice:,
    prefix / part .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thepart }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = part,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / chapter .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thechapter }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = chapter,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / section .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thesection }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = section,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / subsection .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thesubsection }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = subsection,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / subsubsection .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thesubsubsection }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = subsubsection,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / paragraph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \theparagraph }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = paragraph,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / subparagraph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thesubparagraph }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = subparagraph,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / none .code:n = {
        \tl_gclear:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl
    },
    prefix .default:n = none,
    prefix .initial:n = none,
}
\tl_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools / question } {
    label .choice:,
    label / arabic .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \arabic{question} }
    },
    label / alph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \int_to_alph:n { \value{question} } }
    },
    label / lower-alph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \int_to_alph:n { \value{question} } }
    },
    label / upper-alph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \int_to_Alph:n { \value{question} } }
    },
    label / roman .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \roman{question} }
    },
    label / lower-roman .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \roman{question} }
    },
    label / upper-roman .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \Roman{question} }
    },
    label .default:n = arabic,
    label .initial:n = arabic,
}
\str_new:N \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    suffix-character .choice:,
    suffix-character / dot .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str { . }
    },
    suffix-character / colon .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nx \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str { \c_colon_str }
    },
    suffix-character / bracket .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nx \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str { ) }
    },
    suffix-character / none .code:n = {
        \str_gclear:N \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str
    },
    suffix-character .default:n = dot,
    suffix-character .initial:n = dot,
}
\skip_new:N \l__teachingtools_questionbefore_skip
\skip_new:N \l__teachingtools_questionafter_skip

\skip_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_questionbefore_skip { 1.0ex plus -1ex minus -0.25ex }
\skip_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_questionafter_skip { 1ex plus 0.25ex }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { question } { s O { } } {
    \IfBooleanTF #1
    { \bool_set_false:N \l__teachingtools_numbered_question_bool }
    { \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_numbered_question_bool }

    \keys_set:nn { teachingtools / question } {#2}
    \__teachingtools_print_question:

    \itshape
    }
{\par \skip_vertical:N \l__teachingtools_questionafter_skip \thequestion} % The `\thequestion` here is simply to illustrate the changing definition

\NewDocumentCommand \ttsetup { m } {
    \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {#1}
}
\ProcessKeysOptions { teachingtools }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% Most options set with `\ttsetup` can also be applied on specific instances
% of the `question` environment.  Of most use in this scenario is the
% `number` option, which has the same effect as `\setcounter{question}`; the
% others are of limited use but I've made them available anyway.
\ttsetup{
    % prefix-separator = dash,             % (dash|dot|colon|none)
    question / prefix = section,           % (part|chapter|section|subsection|subsubsection|paragraph|subparagraph|none)
    question / reset = none,               % (part|chapter|section|subsection|subsubsection|paragraph|subparagraph|none)
    question / label = upper-alph,         % (arabic|lower-alph|upper-alph|lower-roman|upper-roman)
    suffix-character = bracket,            % (dot|colon|bracket|none)
    % question / number = 1,               % any integer
}

\section{A section}

\begin{question}
    The question in a section
\end{question}

\thequestion  % Should be 1-A, prints 1 instead

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{question}
    The question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}[number = 7]
    Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}\label{qu:test}
    The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\section{Another section}

\begin{question}
    Another question in another section
\end{question}

See also \ref{qu:test}.

\begin{question}
    Another question in another section
\end{question}

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{question}
    The question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}
    The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}
    The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

In a nutshell, this package will define environments to typeset question/answer pairs, as well as a few other things, for use in academic worksheets, like tutorials, textbooks, exams, lecture notes, etc.  In order to provide for the most flexibility, the numbering style of these environments can be changed on-the-fly, either with a dedicated command or by passing options to the environment instances.  The MWE above does these things, as can be demonstrated by changing various options in the `\ttsetup` macro.

My current problem is that I want to also change the way references to labelled `question`s are printed, so that **if the question number is 3-B, the reference will print "3-B" instead of "2"**. Is this possible, and if so, how might I go about doing this?  I've been looking at [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) for some hints, but I think I'll need to make my modifications at the level below; once I get it working I can always add a patch to `cleveref` later.

So far, I've managed to get it to print out the correct label format in the terminal, using the string `\l__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl`; passing that through to `\renewcommand{\thequestion}` via a l3→2e wrapper macro breaks in rather weird ways, as could be expected.  My hunch is that I'm part way there, but I don't know nearly enough about 2e or l3 to get the interfaces to behave in a sensible manner.

Comment: I don't mean to discourage you writing your package but have seen [`xsim`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim)?

Comment: Isn't this how the default system works without your package: if the question number is '3-B', `\ref` produces '3-B'.

Comment: @HenriMenke `enumitem` seems the obvious tool to me, but I have no idea what `xsim` does.

Comment: @cfr `xsim` (formerly `exsheets`) solves the exact same problem `teachingtools` attempts to solve, i.e. typeset question-answer pairs for exercise sheets.

Comment: @HenriMenke it looks like `xsim` has well-and-truly beaten me to solving this particular set of problems :/ , though I do intend to add additional features and environments later on. The package at the moment also has support for `example`s, but I left this out of the question as it wasn't relevant.

Comment: Off-topic: a new environment always initiates a group, so you don't need to group the contents explicitly. And `\itshape` is a switch. Treating `itshape` as an environment works by (intentional on Lamport's part) sleight of hand. But it is still a switch. I'm no expert, but `\cs_new_eq:cN {endexample*} \endexample` really doesn't look right, even setting aside the wholesale repudiation of the l3 naming guidelines. And what is the point of `\cs_new:cpn {example*} {\example*}`?

Comment: You really, really, really should read the naming guidelines. Not only your macros, but your variables all ignore them, too. There's a system to the naming - it isn't required for code to work, but it is required for it to play nicely with other code and to be easily readable by others. `\skip_new:N \questionbefore` is wrong. It should be something like `\skip_new:N \l_teachingtools_questionbefore_skip` or `\skip_new:N \g_teachingtools_questionbefore_skip`, depending on whether you are treating it as local (with e.g. `_set_`, `_clear_`) or global (e.g. `_gset_`, `_gclear_`).

Comment: @HenriMenke Ah. I didn't know `exsheets` had passed away ;). I have never used it. I always use `enumitem` ... well via `cfr-coursepacket`.

Comment: @cfr I'm new to writing LaTeX3 code so this is very much a work-in-progress, and some of the basic ideas were taken wholesale from some macros in older documents of mine. The package itself uses `\l_@@_…` for most variables, and some of the names are a bit awkward as I wasn't sure what to call them. Suggestions are welcome :) .
The `\cs_new:cpn{example*} {\example*}` was meant to be used to create starred (i.e. unnumbered) examples as per [this old answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45401/use-the-s-star-argument-with-newdocumentenvironment); have things changed since then?

Comment: Well, egreg does say he isn't sure it is a good idea. See also the comment by Joseph Wright on the question. I'd suggest asking them if they'd still recommend this. As for suggestions for naming: there's a standard explained in the documentation and you should use that. Names should indicate local or global (for variables), should include a package-specific prefix, a descriptive name and the suffix for the type (for variables). E.g. `\l_teachingtools_before_some_env_dim` for a local dimension or whatever. The first bit and the final suffix are standard. The second bit is namespace-ish.

Comment: I take it that from the lack of responses to the original question that it's not actually possible to do what I had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to do the trick.  The `\g__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl` needs to be rendered by a separate function, and then called once at the beginning of the document to generate the initial value. After that it will be regenerated each time a question environment is created, and that sets the references correctly.

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3keys2e}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \__teachingtools_print_question: {
    \teachingtools_generate_question_label_format:
    \str_clear_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_str
    \str_put_left:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_str { Question }
    \bool_if:NT \l__teachingtools_numbered_question_bool {
        \refstepcounter{question}
        \str_put_right:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_str { ~ }
        \__teachingtools_print_question_label:
        \str_put_right:Nx \l__teachingtools_question_str { \l__teachingtools_question_label_str }
    }
    \str_put_right:Nx \l__teachingtools_question_str { \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str }

    % Prints format string of label in terminal: how can I use this to change the
    % printing of \refl{qu:label}?
    % \tl_show:N \l__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl
    % \cs_gset_nopar:cpx { thequestion } { } { \l__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl }

    \par \skip_vertical:N \l__teachingtools_questionbefore_skip
    \group_begin:
    \bfseries \l__teachingtools_question_str \par\nopagebreak
    \group_end:
}
\cs_new:Nn \__teachingtools_print_question_label: {
    \str_clear_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_label_str
    \bool_if:NT \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool {
        \str_put_right:Nx \l__teachingtools_question_label_str { \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl }
        \str_put_right:Nx \l__teachingtools_question_label_str { \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str }
        \tl_gput_right:NV \g__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl { \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl }
        \tl_gput_right:NV \g__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl { \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str }
    }
    \str_put_right:Nx \l__teachingtools_question_label_str { \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl }
    \tl_gput_right:NV \g__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl { \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl }
}
\tl_new:N \g__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl
\cs_new:Nn \teachingtools_generate_question_label_format: {
    \tl_gclear:N \g__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl
    \bool_if:NT \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool {
        \tl_gput_right:NV \g__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl { \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl }
        \tl_gput_right:NV \g__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl { \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str }
    }
    \tl_gput_right:NV \g__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl { \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl }
}
\newcounter{question}
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools / question } {
    reset .default:n = section,
    reset .choices:nn = {
        part, chapter, section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph
    }
    {
        \counterwithin*{question}{ \tl_to_str:N \l_keys_choice_tl }
    },
    reset / none .code:n = {
        \counterwithout*{question}{section}
    },
}
\bool_new:N \l__teachingtools_numbered_question_bool
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    question / number .code:n = {
        \int_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_int #1
        \int_decr:N \l_tmpa_int
        \setcounter{question}{ \int_use:N \l_tmpa_int }
    },
}
\str_new:N \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    prefix-separator .choice:,
    prefix-separator / dash .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str { - }
    },
    prefix-separator / dot .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str { . }
    },
    prefix-separator / colon .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nx \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str { \c_colon_str }
    },
    prefix-separator / none .code:n = {
        \str_gclear:N \l__teachingtools_prefix_separator_str
    },
    prefix-separator .default:n = none,
    prefix-separator .initial:n = none,
}
\tl_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl
\bool_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools / question } {
    prefix .choice:,
    prefix / part .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thepart }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = part,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / chapter .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thechapter }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = chapter,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / section .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thesection }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = section,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / subsection .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thesubsection }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = subsection,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / subsubsection .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thesubsubsection }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = subsubsection,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / paragraph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \theparagraph }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = paragraph,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / subparagraph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl { \thesubparagraph }
        \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {
            question / reset = subparagraph,
            prefix-separator = dash,
        }
        \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_bool
    },
    prefix / none .code:n = {
        \tl_gclear:N \l__teachingtools_question_prefix_tl
    },
    prefix .default:n = none,
    prefix .initial:n = none,
}
\tl_new:N \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools / question } {
    label .choice:,
    label / arabic .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \arabic{question} }
    },
    label / alph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \int_to_alph:n { \value{question} } }
    },
    label / lower-alph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \int_to_alph:n { \value{question} } }
    },
    label / upper-alph .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \int_to_Alph:n { \value{question} } }
    },
    label / roman .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \roman{question} }
    },
    label / lower-roman .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \roman{question} }
    },
    label / upper-roman .code:n = {
        \tl_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_question_label_tl { \Roman{question} }
    },
    label .default:n = arabic,
    label .initial:n = arabic,
}
\str_new:N \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str
\keys_define:nn { teachingtools } {
    suffix-character .choice:,
    suffix-character / dot .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str { . }
    },
    suffix-character / colon .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nx \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str { \c_colon_str }
    },
    suffix-character / bracket .code:n = {
        \str_set:Nx \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str { ) }
    },
    suffix-character / none .code:n = {
        \str_gclear:N \l__teachingtools_suffix_character_str
    },
    suffix-character .default:n = dot,
    suffix-character .initial:n = dot,
}
\skip_new:N \l__teachingtools_questionbefore_skip
\skip_new:N \l__teachingtools_questionafter_skip

\skip_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_questionbefore_skip { 1.0ex plus -1ex minus -0.25ex }
\skip_set:Nn \l__teachingtools_questionafter_skip { 1ex plus 0.25ex }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { question } { s O { } } {
    \IfBooleanTF #1
    { \bool_set_false:N \l__teachingtools_numbered_question_bool }
    { \bool_set_true:N \l__teachingtools_numbered_question_bool }

    \keys_set:nn { teachingtools / question } {#2}
    \__teachingtools_print_question:

    \itshape
    }
{\par \skip_vertical:N \l__teachingtools_questionafter_skip }
\cs_new:cpn {question*} {\question*}
\cs_new_eq:cN {endquestion*} \endquestion

\NewDocumentCommand \ttsetup { m } {
    \keys_set:nn { teachingtools } {#1}
}
\ProcessKeysOptions { teachingtools }

\renewcommand\thequestion{ \g__teachingtools_question_label_format_tl }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    hidelinks}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\begin{document}

% Most options set with `\ttsetup` can also be applied on specific instances
% of the `question` environment.  Of most use in this scenario is the
% `number` option, which has the same effect as `\setcounter{question}`; the
% others are of limited use but I've made them available anyway.
\ttsetup{
    % prefix-separator = dash,             % (dash|dot|colon|none)
    question / prefix = section,           % (part|chapter|section|subsection|subsubsection|paragraph|subparagraph|none)
    question / reset = none,               % (part|chapter|section|subsection|subsubsection|paragraph|subparagraph|none)
    question / label = lower-alph,         % (arabic|lower-alph|upper-alph|lower-roman|upper-roman)
    suffix-character = dot,                % (dot|colon|bracket|none)
    % question / number = 1,               % any integer
}

\section{A section}

\begin{question}\label{qu:first}
    The question in a section
\end{question}

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{question}
    The question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}[number = 7, label = lower-roman]\label{qu:lowerroman}
    Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}\label{qu:test}
    The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\section{Another section}

\begin{question}
    Another question in another section, which refers to
    \ref{qu:lowerroman}.
\end{question}

See also \ref{qu:test}, and \ref{qu:first}.

\begin{question}
    Another question in another section
\end{question}

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{question}
    The question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Another question in a subsection
\end{question}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}
    The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\begin{question}
    The question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\begin{question}
    Another question in a subsubsection
\end{question}

\end{document}
```