# Star argument in \NewDocumentEnvironment with variable name

Tags: environments, expl3, xparse

I am trying to construct a command which would automatically redefine an environment of given in both starred and not starred version. The goal is to have `\setenviron{foo}` redefining environments `foo` and `foo*`. I tried to use code from [Use the s (star) argument with \NewDocumentEnvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45401/use-the-s-star-argument-with-newdocumentenvironment) to work with star arguments, but I can't use variable name of environment there (replacing `foo` with `#1` doesn't work, even after my attempt to write `\csname #1* \endcsname` instead of `\foo*` and expand it with `\expandafter`). What can I do?

I have no idea how `\cs_new` and `\cs_new_eq` work and I couldn't find any guides online (`expl3` documentation on CTAN doesn't cover these) so I would be grateful for some little explanation of the solution.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newenvironment{foo}{}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setenviron}{m}{%
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{s +b}{%
\IfBooleanTF{##1}{do~~ star~ things\par ##2}{##2}%
}{%
\IfBooleanTF{##1}{\par stop~ doing~ star~ things}{}%
}
\cs_new:cpn  {#1*}  {\foo*}       %I have problem with these two lines
\cs_new_eq:cN { end#1*} \endfoo   %
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\setenviron{foo}

\begin{foo}
normal foo
\end{foo}

\begin{foo*}
starred foo
\end{foo*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An environment *called* `foo*` is no different (except by convention) from an environment called `fooX`, and neither mean that the environment is starred.

An environment called `foo*` is declared exaclty like you'd declare `foo`:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo*}{+b}
  {Starred: [##1]}
  {** starred end}%
```

and you use it with:

```
\begin{foo*}
  <content>
\end{foo*}
```

An environment `foo` that takes a `*` as optional argument is very different.  You declare it as `foo` with an `s` argument:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{foo}{s +b}
  {\IfBooleanTF{#1}{Starred:}{Not starred:} (#2)}
  {env end}%
```

and you'd use it (note how the `*` is *after* the environment begin):

```
\begin{foo}*
  <content>
\end{foo}
```

In your case you just want your command to define two environments, one called `#1` and the other called `#1*`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newenvironment{foo}{}{}
\newenvironment{foo*}{}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\setenviron}{m}{%
  \RenewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{+b}
    {Non starred: (##1)}
    {-- no star end}%
  \RenewDocumentEnvironment{#1*}{+b}
    {Starred: [##1]}
    {** starred end}%
}

\begin{document}

\setenviron{foo}

\begin{foo}
normal foo
\end{foo}

\begin{foo*}
starred foo
\end{foo*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]